# Wordpress: get ACF-field from post-category in menu-walker

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, advanced-custom-fields

A pretty specific problem.
I'm using the menu-walker to create a sub-menu,  on one of the pages I wish to use an ACF-Field from all the posts with a specific category and put it into the menu. The Else
This is my menu walker custom-code, the esle-part works fine, the `if gallery.php` doesn't give an error, only the query_posts-loop doesn't render anything.

```
if ( is_page_template( 'gallery.php' ) ) {
                query_posts('category_name=produktion');
                if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
                 $output .='

                    <li class="prodSub"><a href="#">'. get_field('prod_ens') .'</a></li>
                 ';
                 endwhile; 
                endif;
} else {
    // Returns false when 'about.php' is not being used.
            if (get_field('info_block')): $count = 0;
                 while (has_sub_field('info_block')): $count++;
               $output .='<li><a href="#infoBlock'. $count .'">' . get_sub_field('info_block_header') . '</a></li>';

                endwhile; 
            endif;
              if (get_field('ctc')): $count = 0;
                 while (has_sub_field('ctc')): $count++;
               $output .='<li><a href="#ctcItem'. $count .'">' . get_sub_field('ctc_name') . '</a></li>';

                endwhile; 
            endif;
            }
      $output .= '</ul>';
```

Comment: the else is using `get_sub_field` and the if is using `get_field`.

Comment: Yes, well, because in the else there are repeater fields and in the if there are ordinary ACF-fields, or have I missunderstood the taxonomy?

Comment: We don't actually see how your ACF fields are set up. The issue might be your category name. Usually it's done with the category id like `cat=22`. I've seen it otherwise but then it's in an array like query_posts( array( 'category_name' => 'my-category-slug', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );